# Poisson process (discrete counts) measured over varying time interval with many zeros

Tags: r, regression, poisson-distribution, count-data

I am modeling forest inventory data. Forest plots are visited every 5-10 years. New trees that cross some threshold diameter between census intervals are classified as 'recruits' and counted. Generally, across many forest plots, there are many plots with 0 recruits, and some with some discrete number of recruits.

This seems like a straightforward, zero-inflated poisson problem. However, The re-measurement interval varies from plot to plot. This means plots with a longer re-measurement period will have more recruits, just because they have had more time to recruit.

What is the best way to go about modeling the number of recruits in a plot, given that the re-measurement interval varies from plot to plot? I have so far tried including the re-measurement period as a predictor in my model. It is significant, however I do not think this is the appropriate way to go about doing this.

```
#R code to fit zero-inflated poisson regression model
library(pscl)
m1 <- zeroinfl(recruits ~ x1 + x2 + remeasurement.interval, data=data)
```